# Adding image to JApplet

Tags: image, applet, japplet

I'm trying to add an image to my JApplet, while also making sure that my image is in the same folder, I have tried changing the image extension to .png, .bmp and .gif with no luck, my code is pasted below :

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class Welcome5 extends JApplet
{
    private Image logo1;

    public void init()
    {
        logo1 = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "Kobe.gif");
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawImage(logo1, 0, 0, 400, 400, this);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'changing the image extension'?  Is this one image that has been named `Kobe.png`, then renamed to `Kobe.bmp` etc.?  Can you get the image to load in something that is *not* an applet?  Upload the image so we can look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Emm... I hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6715006/592704) one of my answers will help you

... though it is quite unclear you talking about as "change image extension" :S Do you want to modify a sys image file or something with your applet? So to make your applet work with IO lib?

Comment in more details please

Answer (score 0):

You likely placed the image in the wrong directory. I use eclipse and usually place all of my images in an "images" folder that I place in: 
C:\Users\yourUserName\Workspace\yourProjectName\bin

and then access it by calling "images/Kobe.jpg"
the other file types you mentioned should work...
also check case sensitivity.